# Kcachegrind override list item limit of 499

Tags: kcachegrind

Currently, I can't get my kcachegrind instance to display more than 499 list items.  This leaves me with an incomplete Call Graph.

Is there a way to not skip functions?

Answer (score 5):

Just figured it out...

On Ubuntu :-

Edit this file : ~/.kde/share/config/kcachegrindrc

Change `MaxListCount=499` to `MaxListCount=2499`

or any value you like... make sure your system can support the UI. If the app crashes then reduce that number...